# Issues with ArcGIS Pro and Python for Labeling Point Shapefiles

Tags: python, labeling, arcgis-pro, expression

I am trying to take two separate columns of data and create a stacked label where the bottom line (Benzen_1Q_2019) will be red and a larger font, while the top line (Well_ID) will be a dark grey color and a smaller font. I have symbolized the labels already and am now working on using Python to change the color and the font size. I have gotten the majority of it done, but the one thing I am struggling with is the column (text field) I am using for the second line (Benzen_1Q_2019) has values that are either a whole number or (-) or <1. When I type out out the Python expression, it works correctly for the values that are either (-) or a whole number, but it does not work for the values that are <1.

Any tips for how to make this work correctly?

My expression:

```
[Well_ID] + '\n' + "<CLR red ='255'><FNT size ='7'>" + [Benzen_1Q_2019] + "</FNT></CLR>"
```

[Attribute Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wT8gu.png)
[Python code and labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXgCG.jpg)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXgCG.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [Label Expression](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/text/text-formatting-tags.htm) help, the < (less than) character is being evaluated as part of the expression. Thus your labels get confused.

You can do an inline replace on the the less than:

```
[Well_ID] + '\n' + "<CLR red ='255'><FNT size ='7'>" + [Benzen_1Q_2019].replace("<", "&lt;") + "</FNT></CLR>"
```

There are other approaches (see the previously mentioned doc)